# Quitar el SDK AdMod de la aplicación generada para android

Tags: android, genexus, admob

En las ultimas publicaciones de la app en el play store tengo una advertencia porque el app bundle generado contine el SDK AbMod, un generador de publicidad; en la encuesta respondo que mi aplicación no la utiliza para publicidad pero sigue mostrándome como un error.

**Hemos detectado SDKs de anuncios en tu aplicación**

**Versión: 425, SDK: AdMob**

En la configuración del SD Main está estipulado "***Ads Provider = None***"; pero el generado parece no reconocer el parámetro por eso incluye dicho SDK.
Donde más debo configurar para que no se incluya en el aab el SDK.
Gracias.

Comment: Si no tienes Ads provider no se debe incluir el SDK de Admob. Puedes verificar en el build.gradle del main en la parte de "dependencies".
Adicionalmente puedes ver ahi que otros sdk tienes a ver si alguno hace uso de ads.

Answer (score 0):

Si continuas recibiendo la alerta, puede deberse a dos razones:

1. Aun tienes definido en còdigo el uso de AdMob, si quitaste el còdigo es muy importante eliminar las dependencias, ya que aunque no tengas còdigo par AdMob con el simple hecho de definir la dependencia en tu `build.gradle` continuaras obtenendo la alerta.

Asegura en tu archivo `build.gradle` no tener dependencias con este nombre: `play-services-ads`.

2. Si verificaste en tu aplicaciòn el punto 1) , la segunda causa es que puedas tener otro .APK o .AAB el cual hacia uso de AdMob, revisa si indica tu app usa "2 version codes":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para esto lo que puedes realizar es requerir una excepciòn para el versionCode de tu app que tenìa la implementaciòn de AdMob.

Al asegura los 2 puntos ahora si puedes responde "NO", recuerda que si respondes "NO" y Google detecta haces uso de AdMob tu app podrìa ser bajada de la tienda.